# Pulling a value from JSON and setting a variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am not good with powershell so I was hoping someone could help. I am pulling a JSON result from an API and I need to extract the value of the field called number and assign it to a variable. The JSON is not from a file. The results look like this:

```
<result>
<number>INC000955442</number>
</result>
```

So I need the value of number to to be set to a variable. My url is already narrowing down the API result to only one result as I am using a foreach loop

I have the rest of the script figured out but I am stuck with extracting the value from the JSON.

EDIT: I am converting the XML result from API to ConvertTo-Json - Compress. If there is a way to get it from XML results I could use that too.

Comment: That looks like XML, not JSON :)

Comment: So you have XML embedded in a Json? Please show us an example of the Json

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention I am converting it to JSON

Comment: This is from the powershell ISE ---- {"result":[{"number":"INC000958883"}]}
{"result":[{"number":"INC000958896"}]}
{"result":[]}
{"result":[{"number":"INC000958893"}]}
{"result":[]}
{"result":[]}
{"result":[{"number":"INC000958876"}]}
{"result":[]}
{"result":[]}
{"result":[]}
{"result":[]}
{"result":[{"number":"INC000958890"}]}
{"result":[{"number":"INC000958889"}]}
{"result":[{"number":"INC000958887"}]}
{"result":[{"number":"INC000958857"}]}

Comment: Sorry your question is not clear, you're showing XML and mentioning Json then pasting a Json in a comment that doesnt have any XML in it. Please re-read your question and see if it makes sense to you

Comment: I updated it. English is not native to me.

Comment: You can extract the incident number from that variable using this: `$var | Select-Xml -XPath '/result/number' | ForEach-Object { $_.Node.InnerText }`..